# The circumference of a circle of radius $\sqrt{t}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, circles, jacobian

I calculated the circumference $S_1$ of a circle of radius $r$ using polar coordinates $(x, y)\rightarrow(\rho\cos\theta, \rho\sin\theta)$:

$$
\begin{align}
S_1 &= \int\int_{\{(x, y)|x^2+y^2=r^2\}}dxdy \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\delta(\rho-r)|\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(\rho, \theta)}|d\rho d\theta \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty\delta(\rho-r)\rho d\rho \\
&= 2\pi r.
\end{align}
$$

If I replaced $t=r^2$, $(x, y)\rightarrow (\sqrt{\tau}\cos\theta, \sqrt{\tau}\sin{\theta})$, then Jacobian is

$$
|\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(\tau, \theta)}| = 
\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\cos\theta}{2\sqrt{\tau}} & -\sqrt{\tau}\sin\theta\\\frac{\sin\theta}{2\sqrt{\tau}} & \sqrt{\tau}\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac{1}{2},
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align}
S_1 &= \int_{\{(x, y)|x^2+y^2=t\}}dxdy \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\delta(\tau-t)|\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(\tau, \theta)}|d\tau d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty\delta(\tau-t)d\tau\\
&= \pi.
\end{align}
$$
Why is the second result  $S_1\ne 2\pi\sqrt{t}\ ?$

Comment: Where did you learn to measure the length of a curve this way? If the theory is legitimate, there must be some additional conditions on how you set up the integrals, as this question shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Dirac delta-function, you have to be careful.  In particular, if you have a function $f(x)$ with a single zero at $x_0$, you might think that you can just replace
$$
\int g(x) \delta(f(x)) \, dx \stackrel{?}{=} \int g(x) \delta(x - x_0) \, dx.
$$
But this is not the case;  the proper rule is
$$
\int g(x) \delta(f(x)) \, dx = \int g(x) \frac{\delta(x - x_0)}{|f'(x_0)|} \, dx.
$$
This can be proven by restricting the integration to a small region about $x = x_0$, defining an inverse function $x(f)$ in that region (note that this requires $f'(x_0) \neq 0$), and changing integration variables from $x$ to $f$.  The factor of the derivative in the denominator comes from this variable change.

Thus, if we change variables from $\rho$ to $\tau$, we can view $\rho = f(\tau) = \sqrt{\tau}$ and $f'(\tau) = \frac{1}{2} \tau^{-1/2}$;  so we have
$$
\delta(\rho - r) = \frac{\delta(\tau - r^2)}{\frac{1}{2} \tau^{-1/2}} = 2 \sqrt{\tau} \delta(\tau - r^2).
$$
When integrated over all $\tau$ and $\theta$, this will yield the result $2 \pi r$ as expected.

More generally, when doing an multi-variable integral over a *single* delta-function that is a function of several variables, we have [the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(\mathbf{x}) \delta(f(\mathbf{x})) \,d^n \mathbf{x} = \int_{f^{-1}(0)} \frac{g(\mathbf{x})}{|\nabla f|} da,
$$
where $f^{-1}(0)$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface on which $f$ vanishes and $da$ is the area element on this surface.  In your case, you when you transferred from $(x,y)$ to $(\tau,\theta)$ coordinates, you had implicitly $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - t$;  thus, there should have been a factor of $|2 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}|$ in the denominator of your integral over $\tau$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

The circumference of a circle should be calculated with a line integral, not a double-integral (which would be used for the area of a circle).

The length of $C:=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=a\}$ is given as 
$$L(C)=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$
with the parameterization $(x(t),y(t))=(\sqrt a\cos(t),\sqrt a\sin(t))~;~0\leq t<2\pi$.

Hence,
$$\begin{align}L(C)&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(-\sqrt a\sin(t))^2+(\sqrt a\cos(t))^2}dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t))}dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt adt\\&=2\pi\sqrt a\end{align}$$

Comment: The way OP tried to calculate the arclength was to treat it as an "area" that's infinitesimally thin in one of its dimensions. That's where the Dirac-Delta came from